# Convert Excel to PDF in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to convert Excel file into PDF in Android Kotlin? I came across a few solution but they are all paid versions/require licenses.

I have large recycler view(report of between 1000 to 5000 records) which I need to save as Excel and PDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your data to a CSV file with [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

and generate a pdf a page at a time by drawing a recyclerview/tablelayout in to a PDF with the Android [PDFdocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) class

Answer (score 0):

You could use PDF Library like [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)